# Can a device have both Face and Finger authentication?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt

Trying to implement login option using bio metric authentication. Want to know, can a device have both `FEATURE_FACE` and `FEATURE_FINGERPRINT`. I could find only one device with `FEATURE_FACE`, Pixel 4. But it seems Finger print authentication is not available in it. Checked by disabling Face authentication from the settings, If finger authentication is available it should show up but it didn't.

1. Is there any other phone which support Face authentication other than Pixel 4 ?
2. Will a device should Finger authentication prompt if Face lock feature is disabled from phone settings ?

Comment: Is there currently any device that exposes more than one mode of biometric authentication through the `BiometricPrompt` API? Maybe not. Are devices allowed to do that? Yes, as long as they meet the necessary security requirements.

Comment: @Michael Fingerprint authentication seems to be very common in all the current devices. But for pixel 4 which has face authentication, fingerprint is not showing up. Did they keep it like that to force only one type authentication on a device ?

Comment: The Pixel 4 doesn't have a fingerprint sensor.